how do I fix Magento Category URL to not show the full path?
I'm running the Mirasvit SEO extension in our store and all seems ok, apart from the category URL's which are wrong, they tell me the setting to fix that is elsewhere but I can't find it. Issue is for example in our 'compressor' category, url for that is showing as https://www.autoairconparts.co.uk/catalog/category/view/s/car-air-conditioning-compressors/id/13/ when it should be clean and simple reading as https://www.autoairconparts.co.uk/car-air-conditioning-compressors/ how do I fix it?
I have checked the Catalog>Catalog>Search Engine etc settings and all seems correct, see screenshot. Is there a setting elsewhere I should be checking?enter image description here

I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a programming-related Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?
